# Does calling an API with SSL mean one needs to call it from an HTTPS server site?

Tags: angular, ssl

API v2.0 Notes

SSL only

We require that all requests are done over SSL.

as a noob in api, may i know what are the above requirement means?

as i try to call api with postman, everything works ok. but when calling api with angular on a local machine. there are errors

Please help

Thanks

error as per below on console.log

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

table:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.hotspotsystem.com/v2.0/locations/. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 500

Comment: The requirement only means that you have to call the https://... address of the API. If you post your angular errors it will be useful.

Comment: hi thats the error from console.log

Comment: It seems to be a server error. Maybe wrong parameters? Nothing related to SSL.

Comment: thanks Alex, will retry... appreciate the help!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it doesn't. It just means you need to have an SSL *client* API available.

The fact that you received HTTP status code 500 indicates that the SSL part is working perfectly.